# Read CSV file and convert to Map using Groovy with Jenkins

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to convert csv file into Map.
I saw this code over here:

```
def convertResultFile(String file){
    def testsResults = [:]
    File csvFile = new File(file)
    csvFile.eachLine { line ->
        def parts = line.split(",")
        testsResults.putAt(parts[0], parts[1])
    }
}
```

My csv file is pretty simple (every line have only two words separated by ',')

I got an exception when I'm trying to use `eachLine`.

When I look into `java.io.File`, `eachLine` doesn't exist.

I am using Java 13.

Comment: `csvFile.text.eachLine{}`

Comment: actually eachLine is present in java.io.File in groovy: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachLine(groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use [the `readCsv` utility function](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readcsv-read-content-from-a-csv-file-in-the-workspace):

```
def convertResultFile(String filename) {
    def testsResults = [:]
    def csv_content = readCSV file: filename
    for (def record : csv_content) {
        testsResults[record[0]] = record[1]
    }
    println testsResults
}
```